# What is the best way to destroy related models when a model is destroyed in backbone relational?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have complex nested structure of backbone relational models.
Every time I destroy a model, it is expected that the all models from relation are destroyed.
How do I do it?
Apparantely Backbone-Relational does not take care of it.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code showing the specific relation you have set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to overload the Backbone model destroy method of your custom models. So you can destroy your nested models. And after that you can destroy the model with Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this);

Example:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  destroy: function(){
    var xhr = this.myNestedModel.destroy();
    xhr.always(_.bind(function(){
       Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    },this));
    //or if you don't want to wait for the response without always
    //Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to overloading destroy would be to use events to propagate changes. The exact setup and complexity would depend on the relationships you have defined and also on how you create and destroy your models.